# The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded.Increase the MaxStringContentLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas

Tags: c#, wcf, web-config

I got the following error when i passed an entity object to a WebService

The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxStringContentLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader

I tried to solve this problem by giving the below code in webconfig of Webservice,but the error still remains. Can anyone Help!!!!!

```
 <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MyService" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                   maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Comment: provide client and server side binding. as @peer points, there is definitely a mis-match creating this error

Comment: As @Dhawalk said, can you post your complete service config?  Even though you may have defined larger values for the binding, there's a chance they may not be used for a couple of reasons (depending on what's in your config and what version of .NET you are on).

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the maximum string content length quota on the server and the client. So check your client config. If that is not working, check if you are using the right binding.

Comment: Well am quite sure that am using HTTPS binding so i tried a new binding in my project as well as web service web config <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding
                    name="myBinding"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas
            maxDepth="2147483647"
            maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647"
            maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
            maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

Comment: You have a wsHttpBinding binding on you server and a basicHttpBinding on you client. I'm sure one of them is incorrect, check your server and client bindings and start wcf logging. http://www.google.nl/#hl=nl&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=wcf+logging&oq=wcf+logging&gs_l=hp.3..0l4.1094.3776.0.4014.11.10.0.0.0.0.456.1947.2-4j1j1.6.0...0.0...1c.1.8.psy-ab.i6qtMJ-yY8U&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44697112,d.Yms&fp=d0b94aacaf6da650&biw=2172&bih=674

Comment: Was your web service not HTTPS when you first created your servicereference in Visual Studio? If so, as a quick and dirty solution you could try to delete your reference, remove the entries from ServiceReferences.ClientConfig, then add it all fresh from your existing web service.

Answer (score 0):

Your server side Web config allows large strings, but you also need to modify your client side ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file to reflect that.

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="Binding_MyService">
                <binaryMessageEncoding />
                <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="yourserviceurlhere"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Binding_MyService"
            contract="yourcontracthere" name="MyService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: But i have read somewhere that we needn't create a custom binding while using WCF web service

Comment: You don't, that's actually some modified code I pulled from my own project. If your silverlight client uses basichttpbinding, that's fine. Which it does, as I can see from your responser to peer's comment.

Comment: Technically, if this is only happening on one side of the connection, you only need to modify that side's config files.  In other words, if sending to the service fails, modify the service's config files.  If it's happening on the client, you only need to modify the client config files.